# What are the options for renting an aircraft in the Caribbean with an FAA certificate?

Tags: general-aviation, rental

I've been looking for places to rent planes in the Caribbean, and haven't been able to find anything that wasn't charter service. Does anyone know of any pilot resources or specific rental or flight schools in the Caribbean, specifically the southern Caribbean?

Comment: Renting in the Caribbean seems like a good way to lose aircraft. You know there are smugglers down there that steal boats all the time, then they scuttle them after making their delivery. Also, in the Caribbean aircraft are widely perceived as being magical objects and it is assumed anyone who flies one must be a magical creature worth 100s of millions of dollars. They then charge fees and taxes based on this assumption.

Comment: hahaha. Good to know. Does the above logic apply to flying a plane from the US down the island chain?

Comment: The Caribbean is big and spans many nations all of whom may have their own aviation regulations. You may want to specify a port of origin for more information.

Comment: @Dave I would chose my point or origin based on where I could get an aircraft. But from this, I think I'll just fly down there with a US aircraft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be much better off renting the plane in the United States. It will be difficult to find a rental anywhere in the Caribbean, except maybe Puerto Rico.

You may want to read Greenspun's [Flying in the Caribbean](http://philip.greenspun.com/flying/caribbean). It's a little dated but has good information.

Comment: That link is fantastic. Thanks!